# Sort Data In Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, columnsorting

I am using Node.JS and MongoDB. I've created a report with CSV file and 
this is my code,

```
function buildListCsvContent() {
   var array = [];
   var counter = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < vm.student.length; i++) {
      var row = {
         No: counter + 1
         , Registration_Number: "'" + student.registrationNumber.toString()
         , Name: student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName
      }
      array.push(row);
      counter++
   }
}


var args = {
   data: array
};

downloadCSV(args);
```

How can i sort this report by registrationNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the array using the `sort` function.

Firstly, truncate the number to remove the `'` and then convert the value into an `Number` using the `Number` Object.

Following is a code with sample data, i have taken a shorter version of the Array to demonstrate.

```js
var array = [];
array.push({Registration_Number: "'1"},
{Registration_Number: "'11"},
{Registration_Number: "'12"},
{Registration_Number: "'-5"},
{Registration_Number: "'8"}
);

array.sort((x,y) => {
 var xInt = new Number(x.Registration_Number.substring(1,x.length));
 var yInt = new Number(y.Registration_Number.substring(1,x.length)); 
 return xInt - yInt;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one method:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.student.length; i++) {
    var row = {
        No: counter + 1
        , Registration_Number: "'" + student.registrationNumber.toString()
        , Name: student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName
        , reg_no: student.registrationNumber   // Added this key to use in sorting
    }
    array.push(row);
    counter++
 }
```

Use the `array.sort` method:

```
function compareFunction (a, b) {
    // Here a and b are the two values in any particular instance of comparison
    // a is put before b if return condition is true, not swapped if condition is false
    // return <condition>

    return a.reg_no > b.reg_no // For ascending
    return a.reg_no < b.reg_no // For descending
}

array.sort(compareFunction)
//array is sorted at this point
```

I suggest you play around with the return condition to get a good hang of the working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

-- Sorry, but I can't write comments to the posts  ¯_(ツ)_/¯ --

To clarify what surajck wrote. According to mdn docs if you want to sort numbers you should subtract one from another, ie

```
function compareFunction (a, b)
     // you could wrap values in `Number()` to convert them to numbers, but 
     // in case of subtraction it's handled automatically
     return a.reg_no - b.reg_no // For ascending
     return b.reg_no - a.reg_no // For descending
}

array.sort(compareFunction)
```

If you're returning boolean you might end with inconsistent sorting.

Generally a number should be returned from the callback:

> If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to an index lower than b, i.e. a comes first.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to an index lower than a, i.e. b comes first.

Answer (score 0):

if You Use mongoo db in your Project
Can Use `.sort({create_at:-1})` for example :

```
        Model.find().sort({create_at:-1}).exec(function(err, user) {})
```